# Setting Kendo for Angular rangeArea chart series item color

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-angular-ui

I am trying to set color of rangeArea chart series item by using `[color]="getColor"` function but it is not working. Setting hardcoded values `[color]="'#00FF00'"` works. I still have other chart series items that should be colored by default colors which is why I cannot use `[seriesColors]="colors"` as a `<kendo-chart>` attribute. Help?

```
<kendo-chart>
  <kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-series-item 
      *ngFor="let item of weatherData"
      type="rangeArea" 
      [color]="getColor" // [color]="'#00FF00'" or color='#00FF00' works (colors both series items in the same color though)
      [data]="item"
      fromField="min" 
      toField="max" 
      categoryField="month"
      [opacity]="1"
    ></kendo-chart-series-item>
    // ... other chart series items
  </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>

export class KpiTimelineChartComponent {

  public colors: string[] = ['#00FF00', '#0000FF'];

  public weatherData = [
    [
      { month: 'January', min: 5, max: 10 },
      { month: 'February', min: 5, max: 10 },
      { month: 'March', min: 5, max: 10 },
      { month: 'April', min: 5, max: 10 },
      { month: 'May', min: 5, max: 10 },
      { month: 'June', min: 5, max: 10 },
      { month: 'July', min: 5, max: 10 },
      { month: 'August', min: 5, max: 10 },
      { month: 'September', min: 5, max: 10 },
      { month: 'October', min: 5, max: 10 },
      { month: 'November', min: 5, max: 10 },
      { month: 'December', min: 5, max: 10 },
    ],
    [
      { month: 'January', min: 15, max: 20 },
      { month: 'February', min: 15, max: 20 },
      { month: 'March', min: 15, max: 20 },
      { month: 'April', min: 15, max: 20 },
      { month: 'May', min: 15, max: 20 },
      { month: 'June', min: 15, max: 20 },
      { month: 'July', min: 15, max: 20 },
      { month: 'August', min: 15, max: 20 },
      { month: 'September', min: 15, max: 20 },
      { month: 'October', min: 15, max: 20 },
      { month: 'November', min: 15, max: 20 },
      { month: 'December', min: 15, max: 20 },
    ],
  ];

  public getColor = (seriesItem): string => {
    const color = this.colors[seriesItem.series.index];
    console.log(color, typeof(color)); // Logs the correct color and type (string)
    return color;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was slight code adjustment.

1. `*ngFor="let item of weatherData; index as i"`
2. `[color]="getColor(i)` and finally
3. 

```
public getColor = (index): string => {
  return this.colors[index];
}
```

However I still don't know why the initial solution doesn't work.